# Создание сервиса видео-конференций

Tags: flash, javascript, html5, php

Доброго времени суток.

Встала задача реализовать веб приложение по типу [Big blue Button](http://bigbluebutton.org/).

Требования:

1. Трансляция видео с веб - камеры лектора. (а также записи этого стрима)
2. Возможность показа слайдов
3. Текстовый чат
4. Простые тестовые задания для пользователей.

Если кто то сталкивался с подобным буду признателен за толчок в нужную сторону, литературу, ссылки и прочую инфу по теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это реализуется либо через java либо flash. Тоже подобное собираюсь реализовать. Можно попробывать реализовать на unity3d